# What is the bash script equivalent of ctrl + c in Electron?

Tags: node.js, bash, electron

I've looked all over I'm not sure where I should be looking.

I want to run a `ctrl + c` command from bash script that is being called from Electron but it doesn't seem to work.

I've stripped down my code to make it easier to read:

My `index.js` file

```
var electron = require("electron");
var ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;
var shell = require('electron').shell;
var remote = require('electron').remote
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function runScript(index) {
    var bashScriptRun = spawn('/bin/sh', [directory/runScript.sh]);

    bashScriptRun.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString())
    });
}

function cancelScript() {
    var cancelBashScript = spawn('/bin/sh', [directory/cancelScript.sh]);

    cancelBashScript.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString())
    });
}
```

The `cancelScript.sh` file

```
# Get its PID
PID=$!
# Wait for 2 seconds
sleep 2
# Kill it
kill $PID
```

The console.log confirms that the script continues running even though `cancelScript.sh` has been called.
Also when I try to echo the `PID($!)` variable, it logs an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

Any guides on where can I learn bash scripting/SIGINIT/etc for dummies?

I still can't get my head around it or the docs I've found so far.

Thanks, All

Your help is much appreciated

Moe

Answer (score 1):

`$!` will get the pid of the current shell's most recently started background process, but the current shell hasn't started any so it's blank.

If you want to get the pid of a process you start in from Node.js, you instead have to ask Node.js. In this case, you can get it with `bashScriptRun.pid`

If you want that pid available in your `cancelScript.sh`, you can rewrite your `index.js` to pass it as parameter to the script.

If that's too tricky, you can `killall runScript.sh` to kill anything with that name instead.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've taking a crack at implementing those points. 
I've tried to include the `killall runScript.sh` from the `cancelScript.sh` file but it's not taking, am I getting that right?

Comment: With the above comment I made, I get the error: `No matching processes belonging to you were found`

Comment: Are you specifying the name correctly? Can you see the process you want to kill with `ps`? Does it match the name?